# Auto Suggestion Search Box in master page not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, autocomplete, master-pages

I'm attempting to implement an autocomplete search feature in the master page of my project to be used by other pages inheriting the master page but the function returns an error despite there being data in my database table to return. I have checked that the table name, textbox ID and column is correct but I'm still not sure what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!
This is the script in my master page file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        SearchText();  
    });  
    function SearchText() {  
        $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {  
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                    url: "AutoCompleteService.asmx/GetmovieTitle",
                    data: "{'name':'" + document.getElementById('searchTerm').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",  
                    success: function(data) {  
                        response(data.d);  
                    },  
                    error: function(result) {  
                        alert("No Match");  
                    }  
                });  
            }
        });  
    }  
</script>
```

This is the content of my webservice page:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AutoCompleteService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public List<string> GetmovieTitle(string name)
    {
        List<string> mResult = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data             Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\\QACinema\\QACinema\\App_Data\\QACinemaHomeCopy.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "Select name from movies where name LIKE '+@name+'%'";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    mResult.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
                }
                return mResult;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LIKE '+@name+'%'"; here must be something wrong

Comment: I've used a query like this before and it has worked. I'm not sure it's the cause of the issue

Comment: LIKE  '%@name%''"

Comment: It's still coming up with the error message

Comment: debug to see what `cmd.CommandText` is; return fixed list to GetmovieTitle then make sure other parts are correct.

Comment: Which error thrown by `ExecuteReader`? Seems that your command text is right (try run the query in SSMS to ensure it), but the connection string has wrong format.

Comment: The ExecuteReader doesn't throw an error but the function returns no data